# $a_1=\sqrt{2}$, $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2}(a_n+\frac{1}{a_n})$. Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{2^{n/2}}$.

Tags: calculus, limits

$a_1=\sqrt{2}$, $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2}\left(a_n+\dfrac{1}{a_n}\right)$.

Find $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{2^{n/2}}$$

Let $b_n=\dfrac{a_n}{2^{n/2}}$, then $b_{n+1}=b_n+\dfrac{1}{2^nb_n}$, then $b_n\nearrow$.

So $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$ exists or $\infty$. How to find it?

Comment: I think that a similar argument to the one you used shows that $a_n$ is nondecreasing. The limit $a$, would then be $\infty$ or satisfy the equation $x^2=\sqrt{2}x^2+\sqrt{2}$ (which is not possible). It my also provide you with a rate of growth for $a_n$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz It is $\lim a_n=+\infty$. How to determine its growth rate?

Comment: Oscar Lanzi provided a great answer. That of course tells you also the rate of growth of $a_n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can show that $b_n$ converges using the recursion you derived. For because the sequence increases monotonically, $b_n\ge b_1$, and then

$b_{n+1}-b_n=\dfrac{1}{2^nb_n}\le\dfrac{1}{2^nb_1}.$

Summing this from $n=1$ to $n=\infty$ then gives

$b_{\infty}-b_1\le\dfrac{1}{b_1}\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}=\dfrac{1}{b_1},$

from which the sequence is bounded as well as monotonic, therefore convergent.

Probably the limit cannot be rendered via elementary functions. Numerical approximation with $a_1=\sqrt2,b_1=1$ gives $1.81248$. To compute the limit, we can use a bracketing procedure. We always have $b_\infty\ge b_k$ for ant finite $k$, and by an argument similar to the one used above we may establish the upper bound

$b_{\infty}-b_k\le\dfrac{1}{b_k}\displaystyle\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}2^{-n}=\dfrac{2^{1-k}}{b_k}.$

Thereby

$b_k\le b_\infty\le b_k + \dfrac{2^{1-k}}{b_k},$

where the width of the interval decreases exponentially with $k$.

Comment: How to compute? If I use Stolz, nothing can be rended.

Comment: The problem has $a_1= \sqrt{2}$, $b_1=1$, for a limit of approximately $1.81248$.

Comment: Misread the q, will correct.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Can we find the limit? Of couse, $b_\infty\leq 2$.

Comment: As I said, the exact value is probably nonelementary. However, for any $k$ we have $b_k≤b_\infty≤b_k+2^{1−k}/b_k$, and the width of this interval will decrease exponentially with $k$. Perhaps you might try proving this.

Answer (score 6):

**Some interesting upper and lower bounds on $\frac{a_n}{2^{n/2}}$ for $n\to \infty$**

On a more general framework we have $a_1 = \alpha\geq 1$ and
$$a_{n+1} = \alpha \left(a_n  +\frac1{a_n}\right)$$
for $n>1$.

Let now $\beta = \alpha^2$ and $b_n = a_n^2$. For $n>1$ we then obtain the recursion
$$b_{n+1} = \beta b_n \left(1+\frac1{b_n}\right)^2=\beta b_n + 2\beta + \frac{\beta}{b_n}\tag{1}\label{1}.$$

From \eqref{1} we have
$$b_{n+1}\geq \beta b_n + 2\beta$$
and thus, recursively
\begin{eqnarray}
b_n&\geq& \beta^{n-1}b_1 + 2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\beta^k=\\
&=&\beta^n + 2\left(\frac{\beta^n-1}{\beta-1}-1\right)=\\
&=&\beta^n \left(\frac{\beta+1}{\beta-1}\right)-\frac{2\beta}{\beta-1}=L_n.\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{eqnarray}
Plugging in this result back into \eqref{1} yields
\begin{eqnarray}
b_{n+1}&\leq& \beta b_n + 2\beta + \frac{\beta(\beta-1)}{\beta^{n}(\beta+1)-2\beta}=\\
&=&\beta b_n + 2\beta + \frac{\beta-1}{\beta^{n-1}(\beta+1)-2}
\end{eqnarray}
and again recursively
\begin{eqnarray}
b_n &\leq& \beta^n + 2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\beta^k + \sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{\beta^k(\beta-1)}{\beta^{n-2-k}(\beta+1)-2}\leq  \tag{*}\label{s}\\
&\leq&L_n + \beta^{n-2}+(\beta-1)\int_0^{n-2}\frac{\beta^{2x}}{\beta^{n-2}(\beta+1)-2\beta^x}dx=\\
&\stackrel{\beta^x = t}{=}&L_n + \beta^{n-2}+\frac{\beta-1}{\log\beta}\int_1^{\beta^{n-2}}\frac{t}{\beta^{n-2}(\beta+1) - 2t}dt=\\
&\leq&L_n + \beta^{n-2}+\frac{\beta-1}{2\log\beta}\left[-t-\frac{\beta^{n-1}+\beta^{n-2}}2\log \left(\beta^{n-1} + \beta^{n-2}-2t\right)\right]_0^{\beta^{n-2}}\leq\\
&\leq&L_n +\beta^{n-2}+ \frac{\beta-1}{2\log \beta}\left[-\beta^{n-2}+\frac{\beta^{n-1}+\beta^{n-2}}2\cdot \log\left(\frac{\beta^{n-1}+\beta^{n-2}}{\beta^{n-1}-\beta^{n-2}}\right)\right]\\
&=&L_n + \beta^{n-2}+\frac{\beta-1}{2\log \beta}\left[-\beta^{n-2}+\frac{\beta^{n-1}+\beta^{n-2}}2\cdot \log\left(\frac{\beta+1}{\beta-1}\right)\right]\\
&=&U_n\tag{3}\label{3}.
\end{eqnarray}
Therefore we have
$$L_n\leq b_n\leq U_n.$$
By \eqref{2}
$$\frac{L_n}{\beta^n} \sim \frac{\beta+1}{\beta-1}$$
and by \eqref{3}
$$\frac{U_n}{\beta^n} \sim\frac{\beta+1}{\beta-1}+ \frac1{\beta^2}+\frac{\beta-1}{2\beta^2\log\beta}\left[\frac{\beta+1}{2}\log\left(\frac{\beta+1}{\beta-1}\right)-1\right].$$
In conclusion, recalling our definition of $b_n$ and $\beta$, we have
$$\frac{a_n}{\alpha^n} \sim K$$
with
$$\sqrt{\frac{\alpha^2+1}{\alpha^2-1}} \leq K \leq \sqrt{\frac{\alpha^2+1}{\alpha^2-1}+\frac1{\alpha^4}+\frac{\alpha^2-1}{4\alpha^4\log\alpha}\left[\frac{\alpha^2+1}{2}\log\left(\frac{\alpha^2+1}{\alpha^2-1}\right)-1\right]}.$$

With $\alpha=\sqrt 2$ we get approximately
$$1.7320 \leq K \leq 1.8349\tag{4}\label{4}$$

---

**EDIT**

The upper bound can obviously tightened if we replace the sum of \eqref{s} with an integral on a smaller interval. E.g.
\begin{eqnarray}
b_n &\leq& L_n + \beta^{n-2} + \frac{\beta^{n-3}}{\beta+2}+\frac{\beta-1}{\log \beta}\int_1^{\beta^{n-3}}\frac{t}{\beta^{n-2}(\beta+1) - 2t}dt\leq\\
&\leq& L_n + \beta^{n-2} + \frac{\beta^{n-3}}{\beta+2}+\frac{\beta-1}{2\log \beta}\left[-t-\frac{\beta^{n-1}+\beta^{n-2}}2\log \left(\beta^{n-1} + \beta^{n-2}-2t\right)\right]_0^{\beta^{n-3}}\leq\\
&\leq& L_n + \beta^{n-2} + \frac{\beta^{n-3}}{\beta+2}+\frac{\beta-1}{2\log \beta}\left[-\beta^{n-3}+\frac{\beta^{n-1}+\beta^{n-2}}2\log \left(\frac{\beta^2+\beta}{\beta^2 + \beta-2}\right)\right]=\\
&=&U_n.
\end{eqnarray}
With this new definition of $U_n$ we have that
$$\frac{U_n}{\beta^n}\sim \frac{\beta+1}{\beta-1}+\frac1{\beta^2}+\frac1{\beta^3(\beta+2)}+\frac{\beta-1}{2\beta^3\log\beta}\left[\frac{\beta^2+\beta}2\log\left(\frac{\beta^2+\beta}{\beta^2 + \beta-2}\right)-1\right]$$
so that now, instead of \eqref{4}, we obtain
$$1.7320 \leq K \leq 1.8168$$