# How to calculate the limit of this sequence?

Tags: calculus, analysis

I have a problem of the limit of a sequence. Given

$$a_1=\sqrt{2}, \quad a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2}\left(a_n+\frac {1}{a_n}\right),$$

compute  $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{(\sqrt{2})^n}.$$

Can any one help me solve it?

I try to use pinching theorem to solve it.  One very useful argument used to find limits is called the pinching theorem. It essentially says that if we can `pinch' our limit between two other limits which have a common value, then this common value is the value of our lim.

And I tried several stpes.  My solution will be see attach.  Can any one help me check it？  Since I am a bit careless.  Many thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: It would also be better if your image was typed out in MathJax

Comment: Interesting question! it just lacks some details: eg. what have you tried? why do you wish to have the solution? etc...

Comment: I will share what I have done later. It is a problem of the exercise for the Mathematical Competition of calculus in my hometown.  The  Competition  will be held on November soon  and it is a two hours closed book exam.   This problem is just one exercise for student whose major is not math and want to prepare this exam.

Comment: See this entry point for a lot of related stuff https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4434147/399263. As is $a_n$ is divergent, but $a_n/\sqrt{2^n}$ converges, though not sure the limit has a closed form maybe there is and haven't searched the site fully, closest is https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4426041/399263. There is a trick (with tanh) when the coefficient is $\frac 12$ instead but not with $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I have some solution though I still need to double check.

Comment: @gloria It's a problem for those whose major is not math? Are you sure that you wrote correctly the problem?

Comment: Of course. It is for a math competition problem, not regular stundents.

Comment: @gloria I meant that the problem is far more difficult than a math competition problem. And it's not normal because you said that "This problem is just one exercise for student whose major is NOT math "

Comment: Some of my friends who try to take math competition ask me this problem,  I even do not know where he find it.  He is not math major and he will take the math competition  for not math students part.   I just try to give my solution.  At least it is a math problem and just solve it. No matter it is a math competition problem or not . No matter math student or not.

Comment: I am not math student too. Though I take the course which cover these problem. And I also try to give solution of another problem in an other page, which is definitely a math competition problem for non math student. I can not make sure, though I try something. Can anyone help me for it?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4556215/how-to-solve-this-problem-of-integral-inequality-in-calculus-many-thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:
$$ a_{n+1}-a_n=\sqrt{2}(a_n-a_{n-1})(1-\frac{1}{a_na_{n-1}})\stackrel{?}{\le} \sqrt2 (a_n-a_{n-1})(1-\frac{1}{(2\sqrt2)^2}). $$
In fact
$$ a_n\ge 2\sqrt2\Rightarrow a_na_{n-1}\ge(2\sqrt2)^2\Rightarrow \frac1{a_na_{n-1}}\le\frac1{(2\sqrt2)^2}\Rightarrow1-\frac1{a_na_{n-1}}\ge1-\frac1{(2\sqrt2)^2}=\frac78. $$
So
$$ a_{n+1}-a_n=\sqrt2 (a_n-a_{n-1})(1-\frac{1}{a_na_{n-1}})\ge\frac{7\sqrt2}8(a_n-a_{n-1}). $$

Answer (score 0):

**Not an answer**  but too long for a comment, just a simple observation for the existence.

Set $$b_n=\frac{a_n}{(\sqrt{2})^n}.$$ The question is to compute $$\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n,$$ with the conditions $b_1=1$, and $$b_{n+1}=b_n+\frac{1}{2^n b_n}.$$ Clearly, $\{b_n\}$ is increasing. Let's show that $\{b_n\}$ is bounded. In deed,
\begin{align}
b_{n+1}&=b_n+\frac{1}{2^n b_n}\\
&=b_{n-1}+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}b_{n-1}}+\frac{1}{2^n b_n}\\
&=...\\
&=b_1+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^k b_k}\\
&\leq 1+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^k}\leq 2.
\end{align}
Consequently, the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n$ do exists.

But I cannot calculate the explicit value of this limit yet.